# php foreach statement to insert data into sql only inserting last line

Tags: php, sql, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to use a foreach statement in PHP to insert data from an array into a SQL database. The array can vary from 40 to 80 lines of data. I'm using the following code:

```
foreach ($racelap as $lap){
     $sql = "insert into laps (RaceID,Lap,time,Temp,Humidity) ";
     $sql .= "values ($RaceID,'$lap[0]','$lap[1]',$lap[2],'$lap[3]')";
    mysql_query($sql); 
}
```

The code doesn't give me an error, but it only adds the last line of data, and ignores all other data.

The solution is probably simple, but I can't find it myself unfortunately.

Comment: You shouldn't use any mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since php 5.5 and completely removed in php 7.0

Comment: You should also _actually check for errors_.

Comment: With no idea of what is actually in the `$racelap` array, or how your table is defined and the fact that the code looks ok, how many guesses would you like

Comment: Start by Adding some [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Then if that does not help, `echo $sql;` inside the foreach loop and see if that gives you any clues ___Debugging 101___

Comment: Sorry for using old methods, it's a temporary solution for existing coding (need to re-do it all later). There are no errors that cause the problem, and the `code` echo $sql; `code` only returns the last row of the array.

The racelap array contains all numeric data from a table (which varies from 40 to 80 laps of data), temperature, laptimes.. stuff like that.

Comment: @RiggsFolly _a kitten is strangled..._ you are a genius :)

Comment: Have you done some processing on the `$racelap` array before getting to this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, 
use your query with insert multiple rows using a single SQL INSERT statement
something like this :

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )
```

**CODE** :

```
$sql = "insert into laps (RaceID,Lap,time,Temp,Humidity) values  ";
foreach ($racelap as $lap){
     $sql .= "($RaceID,'$lap[0]','$lap[1]',$lap[2],'$lap[3]') ,";
}
$sql =rtrim($sql,",");
mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, `mysql` is deprecated. batter you can use `mysqli`. Try use with `mysql` bellow code :

```
$sql = "insert into laps (RaceID,Lap,time,Temp,Humidity) values ";

foreach ($racelap as $lap){
    $sql .= "($RaceID,'$lap[0]','$lap[1]',$lap[2],'$lap[3]'), "; 
    if(!next($racelap)) {
        $sql .= "($RaceID,'$lap[0]','$lap[1]',$lap[2],'$lap[3]')"; 
    }
}
mysql_query($sql);
```